# ubuntu won't boot fsck / [373] terminated with status 4

Tags: boot

Gets stuck on the screenshot below, i can't enter an option, if i do recovery mode it gets stuck on eth0, any ideas? Thanks! (Server)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try "M for manual recovery"? If so what were the results? Can you clarify "recovery mode it gets stuck on eth0"?

Comment: i press m but nothing happens, same with f & i, almost like keyboard is not working but it is. In recovery mode last entry is [8.473342] addrconf(netdev_up):etho:link is not ready

Comment: Note to all: this is a server

Comment: @heynnema Server or not, the process for setting up an `fsck` remains the same.  There's no difference for running a manual `fsck`, they just need a Live environment to boot to so they can run the `fsck`, and see what it says from there.

Answer (score 1):

To perform the manual fsck that's being requested...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: This answer is still valuable, so I am undeleting it.  The OP just has to boot up to a LiveUSB, Desktop or Server, and run the `fsck` from the Live environment instead of from their recovery mode.

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you! After finding out this was a server, we finally did try booting to a Ubuntu Server Live USB, and we could never get past recovery mode. Probably needs to reinstall. Did you read the thread/chat that was originally associated with this answer?

Comment: Yes, I did.  You need to select the USB in the BIOS / Boot Menu, usually.  Otherwise, it'll keep booting to the Bad OS.  You can also force it to not mount `/dev/sda`, though I don't remember that command offhand

Comment: Thanks all, i booted to an old linux mint iso i had here and used the command fsck -t -y -f /dev/sda1. Ubuntu works again! thanks heynnema!

Comment: @ThomasWard using my instructions, when you choose root access, it doesn't mount /dev/sda, so you can run the manual fsck directly from there. We didn't have any trouble booting to the USB... but there didn't seem to be any easy way to fsck. I downloaded the server .iso and have been playing with it myself so I can learn a little more about the server environment. Whatever was wrong with the OPs file system, we couldn't get past selecting recovery mode... so I could never get to root... but it's fixed now.

Comment: @ThomasWard oh... I just reread your previous comment... maybe the OP **didn't** actually boot to the USB... and we **were** trying to get to recovery mode in the bad OS! Either way, I didn't see an easy way to fsck from the .iso... I'll keep playing with it...

Comment: @heynnema Boot to the Desktop ISO, open a command line, `sudo fdisk -l` to find the correct partition device name/type, `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdX#`  The same way you'd do an `fsck` on an external `ext4` disk or partition.  That's not a 'server' thing, that's just `fsck`.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, I know how to do that... but I should have said "I didn't see an easy way to fsck from the **server** .iso". Its got an install selection, and a recovery selection... but the recovery selection takes you down a path like it wants to reinstall the server. But I'm determined to figure out a way to fsck from the server .iso (when booted from a DVD/USB). Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @heynnema Ah, yeah, Server ISO's not as nice, unfortunately.  My bad for the misunderstanding :)  Desktop ISO would make it a little easier, yes.

Comment: yes, the server iso doesn't have all the features, desktop iso did the trick, strange but true! thanks guys!